# Convert weird strings to UTF-8 Legible characters from PHP

Tags: php, string, utf-8, utf, iso-8859-1

I'm getting some strings out of MYSQL like this:

```
Ï¼³Ï½ˆÏ½Ï½— Ï¼­Ï½… Ï¼¹Ï½Ï½•Ï½’ Ï¼¢Ï½Ï½„Ï½™ BY Ï¼¹Ï½•Ï½Ï½Ï½™Ï½–Ï½ˆÏ½“
 Ï¼¶Ï¼¯Ï¼©Ï¼
Â É–¢ Ä¿‚ Ç›® Æ¨™ A F Â
```

The are titles that have been submitted by a user, but I cant seem to output them as regular characters. i suspect they might be Japanese characters, but I am not sure. The top of my html looks like this:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

My MYSQL database encoded as:

```
 utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Is there a way to handle this and output them in HTML as readable characters? I'm pulling them out of mysql as a regular string - but they still output as garbage instead of legible characters. Is there a way to fix this? Or is this not utf-8?

Comment: Is your mysql connection set to use UTF8?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: Why are you using 2 character encodings? Don't do that. Remove `<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">`

Comment: @user my mysql says the field is  utf8_general_ci  and its set to utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Comment: It is using 2 character encodings, or one is the collation? You should use the same character sets. This also doesn't show what the PHP side is doing. You really should have UTF8 all the way through.

Answer (score 0):

update php.ini:

```
default_charset = "utf-8";
```

update your mysql SCHEMA:

```
... DEFAULT CHARACTER SET UTF-8
```